# VBoxManage - This app can't run on your PC

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, cmd.exe

How do I run VBoxManage without typing in the full Path?
So I've put the VirtualBox folder in my PATH but I still get an error when running `VBoxManage` or `VBoxManage.exe` from cmd

[image]

```
C:\Users\tom>VBoxManage.exe
Permission denied
```

[image]

If i run it with the full path however, it works.

```
C:\Users\tom>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" 
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.2.18
(C) 2005-2018 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

  VBoxManage [<general option>] <command>
...
```

I've already restarted my system after adding the folder to PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so for some reason I had a different (corrupted) VBoxManage.exe lying around in my Userhome `C:\Users\tom`. Deleted it and now it works.

Comment: It's always useful to remember the `where` command, which shows what command would be executed when a particular name is typed (`where /?` for details).

Comment: thanks, didn't know that existed. Tried `which`, which obviously failed and haven't given it a second thought

Comment: [This reference](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) includes a link to `which.cmd`, the source of a batch file that emulates the Unix `which` command.